# app stops responding with no apparent reason

Tags: c#, windows-8, crash

My dice roller app contains 7 text boxes (three pairs of 'No. Of Dice' and 'Dice Type' and a bonus one) and a button. I intended that each pair of text boxes is read separately, and if it doesn't contains valid numbers ('fate' and '%' are read as numbers for app reasons) it ignores it.

the problem is that when I do not enter valid numbers in one of the 'no. of dice' text box the app stops responding, and eventually returns to the loading page.

note that I've tested each method separately already.

here is the code:

```
namespace DiceRoller
{
public sealed partial class MainPage : DiceRoller.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    Random r = new Random();

    //regular, untouched basic page code here

    private void btnRoll1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //the problem is with the number boxes.
        List<int>[] results = new List<int>[3];
        if (!(ReadInput(textBoxNumber1.Text) == 0 || ReadInput(textBoxType1.Text) == 0))
        {
            results[0] = Roll(ReadInput(textBoxType1.Text), ReadInput(textBoxNumber1.Text));
        }
        if (!(ReadInput(textBoxNumber2.Text) == 0 || ReadInput(textBoxType2.Text) == 0))
        {
            results[1] = Roll(ReadInput(textBoxType2.Text), ReadInput(textBoxNumber2.Text));
        }
        if (!(ReadInput(textBoxNumber3.Text) == 0 || ReadInput(textBoxType3.Text) == 0))
        {
            results[2] = Roll(ReadInput(textBoxType3.Text), ReadInput(textBoxNumber3.Text));
        }
        textBlockOutput1.Text = "Results:" + String.Join(", ",results[0]) + ", " + String.Join(", ", results[1]) + ", " + String.Join(", ", results[2]) + System.Environment.NewLine + "Total:" + ((results[0].Sum() + results[1].Sum() + results[2].Sum() + ReadInput(textBoxBonus.Text)).ToString());
    }

    //METHODS

    private int ReadInput(string input) //tested
    {
        int returnValue = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out returnValue)) ; //the 'out' will make sure that the number has passed
        else if (input == "%") returnValue = 100;
        else if (input.ToLower() == "fate") returnValue = 6;
        else if (input == "") ;
        else textBlockOutput1.Text = "Error: All text boxes should contain a number,       the strings '%', 'Fate'(not case sensitive) or to be blank";
        return returnValue;
    }

    private int Roll(int diceType) //tested
    {
        return r.Next(diceType - 1) + 1;
    }

    private List<int> Roll(int diceType, int diceNumber)//tested
    {
        List<int> results = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= diceNumber; i++) results.Add(Roll(diceType));//if one of the no. textboxes is read as '0', this couln't operate
        return results;
    }
}
```

}

-thanks in advance for helpers

**edit:** i looked at it with the debugger as advised in the comments (thanks) and the error is 'Value cannot be null'. but what value? it doesn't give any clues. thanks again.

Comment: Have you run it under the debugger? If not, I suggest you start there.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - You beat me to it, it sounds like a job for Mr Efften and Mrs EFFEleven

Comment: Mr Efften and Mrs EFFEleven, I like that. Those two will be his bffs in every situation.

Comment: who are Effen and EFFEleven, I might ask?

Comment: http://blogs.interfacett.com/setting-breakpoints-in-visual-studio-2010-to-troubleshoot-c-and-asp-net-code

Comment: should I change the title of this thread?

Comment: @user1461837 It's a joke relating to the F-keys on the keyboard you press to single-step and step-over while debugging. F10 and F11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made an array of lists

`List<int>[] results = new List<int>[3];`

what you really wanted was 
`List<int>() results = new List<int>();`

then add values to this with `results.Add(Roll());`

You'll have more debugging to do to make sure there is 3 values for your final text set

**Edit 2**
This supports the theory

[image]

**Edit..**

Just realised you have 2 roll methods,
You should initialize as sucn before setting them

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
results[i] = new List<int>();
}
```

Comment: you have made a mistake: you wrote "List<int>() results = new List<int>();" where it was supposed to be: "List<int> results = new List<int>();". thank you for the answer